# Python diff is not working in all files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, diff

I'm trying to diff between 2 files in python

I tried using this code:

```
with open(file_1, "r") as file1:
    with open(file_2, "r") as file2:
        diff = set(file1).difference(file2)

with open(file_o, "w") as file_out:
    for line in diff:
        file_out.write(line)
file_out.close()
if os.path.getsize(file_o) == 0:
    print "match"
else:
    print "does not match"
```

But I'm facing an issue using it, it does not work for all files!!

This is totally weird, any idea why ?
and how can I fix it?

if there is any very fast way for diffing 2 files without being sensitive to line order, would be thankful

Thanks

Comment: What is your objective? There are other tools that offer better solutions if you just want to see differences between 2 files.

Comment: I want to check if they are match, if the files don't match, then I want to print the differences to output file

Comment: @MYGz, I would like to have better solutions, specially if they are faster. Thanks

Comment: can you check with binary read?

Comment: @Abhijithpk, I'm not very familiar with this, what do you mean by binary read ?

Answer (score 0):

Do give us more input as to why it doesn't work. Off the top of my head, looking at your code the comparison to see if the file is open or not is plain risky. The inode for the file could have a size even though it is empty. If you want, what you could do is check if diff is empty, rather than the file, that would make for a better comparison.

Comment: nothing special about input files that fails, there are 2 both txt files of 60 lines, I checked the output file, and its empty tho